# PC can be UDP client but not UDP Server. Why?

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to set up a Raspberry pi to transmit data to my PC via UDP. To do this, both devices are connected to my mobile hotspot.

PC IP: 192.168.78.1 
RasPi IP: 192.168.78.57

There are two scripts:

1. UDP Server

```
import socket

UDP_IP = '192.168.78.1'       #Used when PC is server
#UDP_IP = '192.168.78.57'     #Used when RasPi is server
UDP_PORT = 5005

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((UDP_IP,UDP_PORT))

data,addr = sock.recvfrom(4096)
print(str(data))
message = "Hello, I am the UDP Server"
sock.sendto(message.encode("utf-8"), addr)
sock.close()
```

2. UDP Client

```
import socket
UDP_IP = '192.168.78.1'       #Used when PC is server
#UDP_IP = '192.168.78.57'     #Used when RasPi is server
UDP_PORT = 5005

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

message = 'Hi, this is a client'

client_socket.sendto(message.encode("utf-8"),(UDP_IP,UDP_PORT))
data,addr = client_socket.recvfrom(4096)
print('Server Says')
print(str(data))
client_socket.close()
```

The client sends a message to the server and receives a message in response.

When I run the **server code on the RasPi** and the **client code on the PC**, everything works fine.

However, when I run the **server code on the PC** and the **client code on the Raspi**, it does not work.

The server gets stuck on the line `data,addr = sock.recvfrom(4096)`  presumably waiting for a message, while the client gets stuck on the line `client_socket.sendto(message.encode("utf-8"),(UDP_IP,UDP_PORT))`  presumably trying to send the message.

Can anyone help me explain why the connection works with the RasPi as the server but not with the PC as the server?

Comment: Are the IP addresses really correct? An address ending in `.1` is typically used by the router or similar network equipment, not by hosts on the network.

Comment: Also, why not bind to the address `''`, which means the server will listen on *all* interfaces on the host system?

Comment: Is there a firewall active on the PC?